# Can I use 'its'?

Tags: word-choice

> As the vertical object detection is one core strategy of our process, we analyse ***its*** accuracy with respect to the manually delineated reference objects.

I am doubted whether using *its* destroy the smoothness of my sentence.

Comment: What do you mean by _smoothness_ of a sentence? It is not an objective parameter to use when deciding which word is more appropriate.

Comment: I agree with @kiamlaluno here. This is a completely subjective question. But to answer your question, you can't remove its without making the sentence more confusing, and sounds just fine to me. Plenty "smooth" for a technical document, which I assume this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence needs some editing for style and word choice. Try this:

> Because vertical object detection is one core strategy of our process, we analyse its accuracy with respect to the manually delineated reference objects.

**Answer to your question: Yes**, you can use *its* in this sentence unless the publisher's or your employer's style manual specifically says that it's forbidden. It's standard native-speaker English and idiomatic in all the brands that I know about. It's the way most of us speak and write.

Comment: thank you for the comments. I am using this sentence to begin a paragraph. Then, can I start with 'because'?

Comment: @gnp: Yes, you certainly can start a sentence and a paragraph with "Because". You could also use "As", but because that word is ambiguous when used to mean "because", I'm merely stating a style preference. Many native speakers (I am a native speaker of English, but I'm not one of the "many") use both without worrying about it.